# Bug ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, listview, expandablelistview, expand

I'm using an ExpandableListView.
When I click on a group that has a higher position than the last group, the last group collapse, but the new group don't expand.
However when I click on a group that has a lower position than the last, the last group collapse and the new one expand (that's correct).
I don't understand why in the first case the list behaves like that.

There is my onClick method:

```
expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

            for (int i=0; i<listDataHeader.size(); i++) {
                if(i != groupPosition) {
                    expListView.collapseGroup(i);
                }
            }

            //if(expListView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition) == false) {
            //  expListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
            //}

            return false;
        }

    });
```

Thanks for all who will try to resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:

```
expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listDataHeader.size(); i++) {
            if (i != groupPosition) {
                expListView.collapseGroup(i);
            }
        }

    }
});
```

I have tested it it seems to work fine.